# MyBB Multiple user creation using mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mybb

Multiple user creation mysql

I and some friends created a forim a long time ago. We had some users and made a list with their usernames but unfortunately our website was hijacked and lost access to the database. The question I want to know is if there is a possibility that a command on phpmyadmin exists that will create multiple users at the same time from a list.

My steps so far:
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is :-

```
Insert into mybb_users SET username='some_username', email='email_of_person' , password = '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6', salt = '';
```

You can also fill other column of user table of your choice.